# How to resolve "error":402 unknown client " issue while using live chat Cometd in iOS while the still the connection is open

Tags: ios, swift, cometd

How to resolve "error":402 unknown client " issue while using live chat Cometd in iOS  while the still the connection is open and only the server messages not able to reach the client and client messages are able to reach the server ?

How to set **maxInterval** in iOS application to keep the session active ?

Samples to set **maxInterval**